# Build failed after upgrading to Apache Tools for Cordova Update 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

does anyone of you know why I'm getting the following error message?

I'm trying to build a blank project using the latest version of Apache Tools for Cordova (7). Everything was working fine before (up to version 6).

It looks like it has to do with Visual Studio not being able to install the "vs-tac" module due to some failures with nuget, though I find it weird. I also tried to reinstall it, uninstall and install a previous version but nothing worked for me, failing for the same reason.

Thanks!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.37
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
1>  > edge-cs@0.3.0 install C:\Users\grighetti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge\node_modules\edge-cs
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x86-1.0.0-beta6-12256
1>  Restoring packages for C:\Users\grighetti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge\node_modules\edge-cs\lib\edge-cs-coreclr\project.json
1>    CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
1>    GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp'
1>RUNMDAINSTALL : warning : FindPackagesById: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
1>    Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
1>    GET 
1>    GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Text.RegularExpressions'
1>RUNMDAINSTALL : warning : FindPackagesById: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
1>    Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

other similar error messages, then

```
1>  ----------
1>  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
1>     at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
1>     at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__8.MoveNext()

1>  ----------
1>  Restore failed
1>  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
1>  NuGet Config files used:
1>      C:\Users\grighetti\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
1>  Feeds used:
1>      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
```

Comment: What do you get when you try to browse to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp"

Comment: Hi and thank, I get a response saying that "this feed contains no entries." :/ I'm puzzled because if I try to search for it explicitly I can see results

Comment: Actually if I try to manually install the package it fails saying it is not compatible with the project type. I guess the dependencies the build process is trying to download during the compilation process are only required to build "vs-tac" so it does not make much sense to install them manually.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael, we're not behind a proxy server.

Comment: @grighetti One thing to try would be to run "npm install -g edge --loglevel silly" (or "npm install -g edge-cs --loglevel silly") and see what the logs say about the attempted installation. You could also try installing a random NuGet package into a blank Console app to see if that works.